# AWS CDK hanging on creating ECS resource pulling containe image from ECR

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cdk, amazon-ecr

I'm creating an `ApplicationLoadBalancedFargateService` with AWS CDK and on deployment, the Fargate resource hangs on `CREATE_IN_PROGRESS`. The container image that I'm attempting to use comes from AWS ECR, which I am loading like this:

```
const repo = ecr.Repository.fromRepositoryName(
  this,
  "Repo",
  "repo-name"
);
const image = ecs.EcrImage.fromEcrRepository(repo);
```

I'm getting the following logs over and over in the terminal:

> [21:25:49] [AWS cloudformation 200 0.509s 0 retries] describeStackEvents({ StackName: 'StackName', NextToken: undefined })

> [21:25:50] [AWS cloudformation 200 0.295s 0 retries] describeStacks({ StackName: 'StackName' })

> [21:25:50] Stack StackName has an ongoing operation in progress and is not stable (CREATE_IN_PROGRESS)

I'm wondering if it has to do with the `NextToken: undefined`, but I'm not sure what that is and can't find anything in the docs or on Google. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: View the stack in the cloudformation web console and its Events tab will show you what it's doing

Comment: @erik258 It just says "Resource creation Initiated". I should have stated in the OP, but I've scoured the console as well and have not found any indication of what is happening.

Comment: Most likely your container is crashing. Go to the ECS console and check the service logs.

Comment: I have same problem. How did you fix this

Comment: @Nux I can't remember specifically but it was indeed a container issue. There was an error on starting the server on the container, but the error wasn't apparent. I would start doing some digging in the container logs.

Comment: @FRMR I have the exact same problem right now, too. Where did you check the container logs? I'm not seeing anything inside the ECS console. I'm using ContainerImage.fromAsset.

Comment: In my case, it was a failing healthcheck since I did not implement a proper response for it. AWS then killed the container because of the failing healthcheck and attempted to start it all over again.

Comment: @theovier sorry for the late reply. It was the same for me, glad you figured it out